# Find the equation of a line in a 3D space which crosses two another lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a task to find the equation of a line in a three-dimensional space which crosses two another lines with equations (on photo). We also have a point `A(1, 2, 1)` which is on our line.

I thought when I multiply direction vectors of lines `k` and `l` I will get another vector which will be direction vector of our finding line.

[image]

I know my solution is wrong. Why I can't use this rule here?[image]

Correct answer is:

[image]

Update:
Ok. I have an idea why it's wrong. If this two lines will be in the same plane, then the cross product won't be direction vector of our line, right?

Comment: A line in $3d$-space doesn't have a single line as an equation.

Comment: @Bernard, yeah, I know. Probably, I have explained a little bit messy. I need to find a  parametric or another type of equation which show line in 3d. It's difficult to explain in English for me :)

Comment: Then it is three equations you're after (a single in vector form).

Comment: @Bernard, do you mean [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#As_a_vector_equation)?

Comment: More generally, $M=A+t\vec u$.

Comment: With your method you found the direction perpendicular to both lines, but that is of no use here: why on earth should the requested line be perpendicular to $i$ and $k$?

Comment: @Aretino, ooooh, indeed! I got it. This mistake is about bad drawn lines. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: All the more so as two non-coplanar lines have single perpendicular line (meeting both) and this common perpendicular has no reason to pass through $A$ in general.

Comment: No two lines are skew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT. Find the equation of the plane passing through $A$ and $l$, then find its intersection  $B$ with line $k$. Line $AB$ is the requested line.

Comment: Yes, $l$, sorry: I couldn't read that well.

Comment: `Find the equation of the plane passing through A and l` - but what if `l` is not a  perpendicular line?

Comment: @entithat I don't understand: perpendicular to what? Do you know how to find the equation of a plane passing through a given point and a given line? That's always possible, of course.

Comment: I mean I know how to find the equation of the plane which has a point and a Normal vector (which is perpedicular). [Ok, I found smth](https://youtu.be/AncVA3cX7aQ)

Answer (score 1):

Let L' be the desired line. We mut find a vector in the direction of L'.Since L and L' intersect, there is a plane, which we'll call $\Pi _1$, containing L and L' Similarly there is a plane,which we'll call $\Pi _2$ containing K and L'.The points (1,2,1) and (1,-3,1) are both in the plane $\Pi _1$ so we subtract their coordinates to obtain the vector [0,5,0] in the plane $\Pi _1$. The vector [1,-2,2] is also in the plane $\Pi _1$. Thus the vector $$[0,5,0] \times [1,-2,2] $$ is normal to the plane $\Pi _1$The points (1,2,1) and (2,2,0) are both in the plane $\Pi _2$ so we subtract their coordinates to obtain the vector [-1,0,1] in the plane $\Pi _2$. The vector [2,1,3] is also in the plane $\Pi _2$. Thus the vector $$[-1,0,1] \times [2,1,3] $$ is normal to the plane $\Pi _2$The line L' lies in both planes, so a vector in the direction of L', which we'll call $[a,b,c]$ must be perpendicular to the normals to both planes. Thus $$[a,b,c]=([0,5,0] \times [1,-2,2]) \times ([-1,0,1] \times [2,1,3]) $$ The equation of L' is $x=1+aT,y=2+bT,z=1+cT.$